# Lemmatize tokenised column in pandas

Tags: pandas, nltk, lemmatization

I'm trying to lemmatize tokenized column comments_tokenized

[image]

I do:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 

# Init the Wordnet Lemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def lemmatize_text(text):
    return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in df1["comments_tokenized"]]

df1['comments_lemmatized'] = df1["comments_tokenized"].apply(lemmatize_text)
```

but have

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

What can I do to lemmatize a column with bag of words?

And also how to avoid the problem with tokenization that divides [don't] to [do,n't]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close on your function! since you are using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) on the series, you don't need to specifically call out the column in the function. you also are not using the input `text` at all in your function. So change

```
def lemmatize_text(text):
    return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in df1["comments_tokenized"]]
```

to

```
def lemmatize_text(text):
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in text]  ##Notice the use of text.
```

An example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[["cats","cacti","geese","rocks"]]})
                             A
0  [cats, cacti, geese, rocks]

def lemmatize_text(text):
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in text]

df['A'].apply(lemmatize_text)

0    [cat, cactus, goose, rock]
```

Comment: How do I do that for `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[["cats are playing","He is running","The were fishing"]]})`?